# Best way to upgrade a mail server

Tags: upgrade, dovecot

I have a 16.04 based mail server that is based on fetchmail (no direct inbound mail), dovecot and procmail (to sort the mail) and it has server me well for a number of years.

I decided today to try an upgrade to 18.04, but with the massive changes to courier and dovecote it failed to run after the upgrade (thank goodness for snapshots).

I realise that it was probably naive to suspect that it was going to be that easy.

So.. the question is, whats the best way to upgrade the mail server, am I better trying this again (with some more detailed research) or am I better off just staring from scratch on a new server with either dovecote again or zimbra or something else, and migrate the email into it from the old server?

Thoughts?